# Как 3-му элементу в списке задать цвет?

Tags: java, android

Как в RecyclerAdapter задать элементу, находящемуся на 3-й позиции, цвет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядковый номер можно получить из `position` в `onBindViewHolder`. Цвет можно задать через фон корневого элемента разметки ячейки. Примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position == 2) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```